# Power and control 3 phase ac induction motors with dc source

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, induction-motor, motor-controller

#### Background

So we are making a drive system to be used in a medium sized catamaran. The catamaran will use two water-jets powered by two 3 phase 380v ac induction motors. The entire system will be powered by two large 48V dc battery packs.

As the motors are powered from dc batteries we need to convert this to 3 phase ac and then transform it up to 380 and apply a speed controller. But this entire system becomes quite expensive, so instead we are thinking of creating our own conversion and speed-control system.

#### Question

So I am looking for a controllable circuit(preferably with pwm) to generate required 3 phase output that i can use to drive mosfets that will switch the main dc input. I will later transform this to my required voltage level.

Comment: Why did you choose 380 V induction motors when your supply is 48 VDC?

Comment: And you presumably want a full design (including any code) and BoM for free?

Comment: @Brad the supply could be setup differently, but we already have the 380V induction motors and they are good quality.

Comment: @Andy I am just looking for schematics for a pwm to 3 phase sine wave converter or a better option to setup a ac induction motor with dc, just a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is entirely possible, but what is your timeframe and budget? You might be better off taking an off the shelf DC-DC converter to get your 48V up to ~500VDC and then feeding that into the DC link of some off the shelf variable frequency drives.

Variable frequency drives take 3-phase AC, rectify it to a high DC voltage and then pulse-width modulate six IGBTs to chop that DC bus into three-phase AC of any voltage and frequency to give you easy control of AC induction motors. Almost all of them allow a "common DC bus" configuration mode where the rectification stage is unused, and this is what you'd want to do.

In fact, even if you have to design your own 48V or 96V to 500V DC-DC converter you'd be better off than trying to create your own three phase PWM drive. I'd start looking at the DIY electric car enthusiasts for tips on this DC-DC converter.

Answer (score 0):

http://universal-power.gmc.globalmarket.com/products/details/three-phase-pure-sine-wave-solar-48v-to-110v-inverter-10000w-3279253.html

Inverter from 48VDC to 3 phase 380V. It appears, it already exists.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't anything to invent here. The standard DC to three phase inverters are bog standard and not expensive, even offering masses of controllability such as max Hz settings and gearbox ratio input so the output is the shaft speed.

The controller is going to be a 2 Watt 5k pot on the dashboard. Use a big knob!

Usually a rating well matched to the motor will have a current limit of 1.5 times the plate current of the motor. You can get a bit clever to maximise the power by running the motor on 71 Hz not 50. Above that it will start to drop the current so you don't gain anything.

If that is not clear, you get the most power out of a standard 50 Hz inverter that has a 1.5 current limit by operating the motor at 1.4 times the plate frequency.

For the boat, choose a gearbox or prop that matches the motor speed for max efficiency. I would put a max Hz on motor that avoided cavitation or 110 Hz, whichever is the lower. Check the gearbox for such things as well.